# Symfony2 and twig - Collection of Forms submission - HOW TO SUBMIT SOME FORMS ONLY

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, formcollection

I am using the Symfony example to build a collection of forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Everything works fine except when I am submitting all thse forms.
I have something like a collection of 190 forms in a single one.

When submitting, I am getting a timeout:

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/git/merrin3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/Constraints/FormValidator.php line 212
```

I have here the possibility to increase the max_execution_time

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

But my idea was to reduce the number of forms to submitt.

In fact, the user will have the possibility to edit those 190 forms, but I would like to ask him to check a checkbox for the form that he would like to submit. So, if he selects only the form 1 and 2, only thos etwo should be submitted, not all the 190.

Any idea on ho to do that ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Symphony form collection and the page does not open, but why don't you use javascript to detect in which form fields were changed? That way the user does not have to select anything and only the necessary forms are submitted. I assume javascript is used anyway if you are submitting multiple forms.

Comment: Hi jeroen, their website sems to be down. Simfony can manage multiple forms (Forms Collection) and I tought not using Javascript in this case. So your idea is to use Ajax instead of basic submit form?

Comment: I would assume they are using that already to submit multiple forms but you'd have to check. Otherwise I would definitely use ajax as then every form will have its own timeout as well.

Comment: In this case, I will have to change my submission structure, I am looking forward to another Symfony way solution to submit only some forms, or to only parse some of them.

Comment: In that case you could set a hidden field in each form when a field in that form is changed (using javascript) and check for that at the back-end. You could even use js to clear / delete the unchanged forms on submit to avoid submission completely.

Comment: I tryied to clear the unchanged fields manually, but on the back-end side, Symfony is still generating a Maximum execution time error when doing `$form->handleRequest($request);`.

Comment: Just remove the forms completely using javascript so that they will not get submitted.

Comment: But I do not have forms, Symfony generates one single form with a lot of inputs and then somehow it parses all this collection of forms.